# created_at and updated_at saving as tomorrow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, timezone

When objects are created in our Rails app, it's saving in the Postgres DB 7 hours ahead of our time (PDT). Looks like it's saving everything to UTC. This really screws up analytic graphs, ect.

I have these set in **application.rb**

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

How can I get everything to save/timestamp to the PDT timezone?

Comment: What sql type are you using to store the info?

Comment: yeah rails' timestamps use utc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is (probably) being saved at the timezone of your server, and is independent of your code.   IE, it's your database setting the created_at/updated_at date time (which is defaulting to UTC)

What you need to do is make your analytics work with UTC and translate to PDT, not vice versa.  That gives you a solution that is totally independent of where you are hosted, daylight savings time changes, where your users are, etc.

Consider the simple case of if you have users in multiple time zones.  Someone in EST will hate you west coast PDT people 'cause they always have to translate it ;)

All in all, use and work with UTC - it's... Universal!

Comment: Thanks @Tim, I like your answer, good advice in general. I'll work on translating our graphs to PDT.